# How to avoid getting COVID in an air-conditioned office building

Tags: health, air, work

I work in an office in a building with central air. I leave the office door closed when I am inside, and no one else comes in. I don't know much about the ventilation in the building, other than that it is a "normal US office building," built sometime during the past 20 years, in the northern half of the US, during winter.

- Should I put something over my AC vent (i.e. a filter or something to block it entirely)? Why or why not?
- Are there any easy other actions I can take to reduce risk (other than wearing a mask or not going into the office)?
- Does the answer change based on how much the AC is pulling in air from outside the building versus just recirculating it throughout the building?

Comment: Vote to close, does not seem to need a lifehack.  Get vaccinated, wear a mask.  No "out of the box" solution there.

Comment: Respectfully, I am asking whether there is a lifehack related to this. I don't think that's crazy to ask. Experts have recommended lifehacks in various situations: https://twitter.com/DrEricDing/status/1451986414233661443 But if there is no lifehack, so be it. If @ZeissIkon posts "no, there is nothing you can do to improve on your existing ventilation system" as an answer, I will accept it. I think that would be useful for other people to know.

Comment: Questions like this have been asked before on this site. We cannot provide definitive answers to questions such as this.

Comment: You can't put a fine-enough filter over it to make any difference. Blocking it may bring 'corporate' trouble. You'd need the building plans to know how much is fresh vs recycled air. Working from home is the best alternative - companies all worked out how to do that last year, so this year is simple. In London, as soon as Omicron made headlines, the City deserted again.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin--I'm guessing that it may also not be trivial to block it correctly. Here's hoping they'll let me work from home!